# Get all possible combinations

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting, select, combinations

I have DB with

```
|x1|y1|z1|c1|
```

I would like to extract all combinations possible like:

```
x1 
x1 y1
x1 z1 
x1 c1 
x1 y1 z1 
x1 y1 c1 
x1 z1 c1
x1 y1 z1 c1 
y1
y1 z1 
y1 c1
y1 z1 c1 
z1 
z1 c1 
c1
```

How I can do it using SQL?

Comment: My God, no. Do not try to implement this in SQL. Use application instead - and there's many standard implementation of permutations & subsets selections.

Comment: Trying to understand this. You mean you have a DB table with one field containing the 4 records specified?

Comment: You really should consider solving this using stored procedures or at the application level. But, you can achieve this basically joining tables, consising of one column values `SELECT DISTINCT t1.v, t2.v... FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 v FROM TABLE) t1, (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN2 v FROM TABLE) t2...`

Answer (score 0):

```
with combi (old, new) as                                     
(select 'x1y1z1c1', '               ' from sysibm/sysdummy1  
 union all                                                   
 select substr(old, 3),                                      
        strip(new) concat substr(old, 1, 2) from combi       
        where locate(substr(old, 1, 2), new) = 0             
 union all                                                   
 select substr(old, 1, 2) concat substr(old, 5),             
        strip(new) concat substr(old, 3, 2) from combi       
        where locate(substr(old, 3, 2), new) = 0             
 union all                                                   
 select substr(old, 1, 4) concat substr(old, 7),             
        strip(new) concat substr(old, 5, 2) from combi       
        where locate(substr(old, 5, 2), new) = 0             
 union all                                                   
 select substr(old, 1, 6),                                   
        strip(new) concat substr(old, 7, 2) from combi       
        where locate(substr(old, 7, 2), new) = 0    
)                                                   
select distinct new                                 
from   combi
```